# Where is the dividing line on repair questions?

Tags: discussion

We have the previous question [Are equipment repair questions on-topic?](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96/are-equipment-repair-questions-on-topic) which seems to have led to rather a stale mate as to if repair questions are even on topic at all (the majority of votes are that they belong more on electronics than A/V Production), but where is the line where it becomes something that belongs on another site?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I think anything beyond common wiring problems and basic repairs really belongs on Electronics.  A certain amount of stuff, such as wiring up an adapter or doing some quick basic soldering work that can be done in the field is probably worth having on topic since it can typically fit within an Audio/Video Production environment.

For me however, anything that goes beyond what I would attempt in the field as an "on the job" repair I would personally consider to no longer be Audio/Video production related as it is then going beyond what I would do to make the show go on and instead is delving into the exclusive realm of electronics repair.

I would also argue that any repairs that are not related to traditional A/V gear are not on topic (for example repair of instruments).